# How to insert httpx/asyncio in python code?

Tags: python, json, api, asynchronous, python-asyncio

I have the below code that fetches data from Coinmarketcap api and sends me a telegram message when parameters are met. When I fetch 100 coins then the code works fine. But when I fetch 5000 coins the code is very slow.

A good answer is insert httpx/asyncio in the code (thanks Rubin Pawel). Does someone know how to insert httpx/asyncio into the code?

```
from tokens import cmc_token
import json
import re
import requests
from datetime import date
import datetime
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import schedule
import time
import pandas as pd

lijst = []
price_change2 = []
coinlist = []

def tg():
    token = 'xxxxxxxxxxx'

    def write_json(data, filename='response.json'):
        with open(filename, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(data, f, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False)

    url = 'https://pro-api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/cryptocurrency/listings/latest'
    params = {'start': '1', 'limit': '5000', 'convert': 'usd', 'sort': 'date_added','sort_dir': 'desc' }
    headers = {'X-CMC_PRO_API_KEY': cmc_token}

    d = requests.get(url, headers=headers, params=params).json()
    
    def send_message_two(text='bla-bla-bla'):
        url = f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{token}/sendMessage'
        payload = {'chat_id': xxxxxxx, 'text' : text}

        p = requests.post(url, json=payload)
        return p


    for x in d['data']:
        date_json1 = x['last_updated']
        new_date1 = datetime.fromisoformat(date_json1[:-1])
        new_date_plus1 = new_date1 + timedelta(hours=2)
        new_date_str1 = new_date_plus1.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

        price_now = x['symbol'], new_date_str1, x['quote']['USD']['price'], x['platform']
        price_change2.append(price_now)

        Dataset = pd.DataFrame(price_change2)
        df_new = Dataset.rename(columns={0:'coin', 2:'price', 1:'last_updated', 3:'platform'})
        zx = df_new.sort_values(['coin','last_updated'])


        zx['change1'] = zx.groupby('coin')['price'].pct_change().mul(100)
        zx['change1'] = zx['change1'].fillna(0)

        js = zx.to_json(orient="table")
        parsed = json.loads(js)

        for bn in parsed['data']:
            rt = bn['coin'], bn['change1'], bn['last_updated'],bn['price'], bn['platform']

            if bn['change1'] is None:
                return 0


            if bn['change1'] > 35 and bn['change1'] < 100 and bn['coin'] not in coinlist:
                coinlist.append(bn['coin'])
                send_message_two(rt)
                send_message_two('15 min change 35% all time')


schedule.every(900).seconds.do(tg)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

def main():
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: If you can request 5000 coins in one HTTP request anyway, then using httpx or asyncio won't likely help you at all. (As an aside, why on Earth do you import Datetime in 5 different ways?)